# Want to show different categories wise product list but dont want to add sell or add cart option them in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have to create a website for a ngo [non profit organization]l using drupal 7. There are many basic page and it is website as simple website as others. The ngo have many products which are delivered to necessary person at free of cost. So i want to show on website product catalogs with sub category only but dont Want to sell them online or add to cart option there is one method i know to create content type of different type and attach it with view. But i want to better then it. Show please guide me there is better option or module for it
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating 1 content type "Products" and a taxonomy "Category". After, use the [views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to display your products listing. Manage the display of you content type to create the single page of a product.

Good tutorial on Setting a product catalog : https://www.drupal.org/node/2232015